# *Solved* Can I run Spring Boot as a client with Digest authentication request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, digest-authentication

I need to run Spring Boot that make HTTP request to another Sprin Boot service with Digest authention

Question:

1. Which Spring Boot dependency that i should select on Spring Initializer
2. Can someone show me the example code (I'm a beginer for Spring Boot)

[This is my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELEqg.png)

---

I found the solution in this link https://www.baeldung.com/resttemplate-digest-authentication

Thank you everybody

Comment: 1)You can select  Spring Web and Spring Security in Spring initializer     2) For your reference https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-security-digest-authentication-example/

Comment: Sorry bro. Thank for your ans but I need to create another one. Please see this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELEqg.png

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to have below dependencies in your pom.xml.

- spring-security-web
- spring-security-config

For more details please refer this [Spring Security Digest Authentication](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-digest-authentication)

Comment: Thank for your answer but that one is how to create the Spring Boot service with digest authen, but I need to create  the Spring Boot client refer as my picture. Please see this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELEqg.png